# PocketSphinx can't read from stdin when executed by NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to pass a stream of data from NodeJS to a pocketsphinx_continuous process. My idea of how to do this is to use NodeJS's pipe functionality to send my data to the stdin stream of the pocketsphinx process.

If I run

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /dev/stdin -nfft 2048 -samprate 44100 -keyphrase "hello computer" -kws_threshold 1e-18
```

on the command line then pocketsphinx_continuous launches and waits patiently for stdin input.

However, when I add

```
var ps = exec('pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /dev/stdin -nfft 2048 -samprate 44100 -keyphrase "hello computer" -kws_threshold 1e-18', function(error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

to my NodeJS program, I get:

> FATAL: "continuous.c", line 158: Failed to open file '/dev/stdin' for reading: No such device or address

I'm struggling to understand why I would get this error when running under NodeJS but not when running normally.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: It is better to use node-pocketsphinx instead of subprocess, this way you'll be able to handle errors in a much more straightforward way.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I had issues with node-pocketsphinx having very poor documentation. It seems the original version by moneppo has decent documentation though, I was looking at the official fork before.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by "decent documentation"? A couple of paragraphs in README or what?

Comment: No seriously, is this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moneppo/node-pocketsphinx/master/README.md a "decent documentation"?

Comment: Hmm you're correct, the documentation on the original is bad too. The reason I said it was decent is because of the sentence "A PocketSphinx object is a writable stream that accepts mono 16 kHz 16-bit PCM data." which at least tells me a little bit about how I'm expected to use the package. The cmusphinx version tells me nothing useful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [an issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3530) on the nodejs GitHub which answered my question.

I've adjusted my code to the following and it now works:

```
var ps = exec('cat | pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /dev/stdin -nfft 2048 -samprate 44100 -keyphrase "hello computer" -kws_threshold 1e-18', function(error, stdout, stderr) {});
```

Piping through cat converts the socket stdin that NodeJS creates for child processes into a pipe stdin that allows /dev/stdin to work.